# scilab 5.4.1 is plotting blank graphs

Tags: graphics

I have worked with earlier versions of scilab without any problem in plotting graphs, but when I installed scilab 5.4.1 in Linux UBUNTU 12.04 it is plotting blank graphs in graphics window number 0. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: its a known registered bug..

Answer (score 2):

The same problem happens with Scilab 6.0.2 installed from apt. In order to make plots visible, I had to install an older version of `libjogl2-java`. Example working version: `2.3.2+dfsg-5`.

On Ubuntu 18 I installed `libjogl2-java` from Debian stretch sources:

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  debian-archive-keyring &&\
  sudo ln -s /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive*.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ &&\
  echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libjogl2-java.list &&\
  apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-downgrades \
  libjogl2-java=2.3.2+dfsg-5
```

I was inspired by: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1650958 .
Also, I created a docker image with Scilab: https://github.com/kudulab/docker-scilab-gdojo .

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this issue is to launch Scilab using a dedicated graphics card.

First, add the Scilab launcher in app launcher. Then <kbd>right-click</kbd> on the Scilab app launcher icon you just added and select *Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card*. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem of `libgl1-mesa-dev` that is for providing GLX and DRI capabilities: it is capable of both direct and indirect rendering.  For direct rendering, it can use DRI
modules from the libgl1-mesa-dri package to accelerate drawing.

Open Synaptic and search for mesa and check for libgl1-mesa-dev then install it, if its already installed then uninstall it and see whether you have the same issue or not else install it again.

[image: libgl1-mesa-dev in synaptic]

you can also do it manually but thats comparatively hard, So using synaptic is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i just install all dependencies for ubuntu 22.04 and scilab 6.1.1. and change LIB_GL to MESA_GL. for easier use, i just create export command on basrc file to do this lib change. refer to this link https://www.researchgate.net/post/Scilab-plot-window-not-generated

Comment: This is not a complete answer. What dependencies?

Comment: Its say to update driver to MESA_GL as mine is mesa intel detected. After update the probem still exist before you run the app via command line using MESA_GL flag enabled following to my attached link. So because i othen use the scilab, i added command to .bashrc.

Comment: You missed my point. How does the driver get updated? The steps should be in the answer. How do I edit the bashrc file? The steps should be in the answer. Please read this https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer